# How to allow only subnet for port with iptables

Tags: ubuntu, ip, firewall, iptables, subnet

What i am trying to do is to DROP any packets to specific UDP port, except those one from my secured subnet 10.8.0.0/24.

```
iptables -t nat -A --src 10.8.0.0/24 -p udp --destination-port 63210 -j ACCEPT
```

I get this error: `Bad argument: 10.8.0.0/24`

I don't understand why this does not work...

- Why this command says IP is bad argument?
- How to DROP any other packets, outside subnet?
- Should i use NAT table?
- How to achieve this?

I've found solution like this:

**UPDATE**

```
iptables -N xchain
iptables -A xchain --source 10.8.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A xchain -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT -p udp --dport 63210 -j xchain
```

After applying this, i cannot access port from ANY ip...

**PROBLEM**
I have OpenVPN server set on tun0 interface, forwarding packets to eth0 like this:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth0 \
         -s 10.8.0.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT

iptables -I FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED \
         -j ACCEPT

iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o eth0 \
          -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```

Question is, how to catch tun0 traffic and filter it, instead of eth0, where IPs getting real.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather then trying to block on the NAT table try FORWARD table.

> iptables -A FORWARD --src 10.8.0.0/24 -p udp --destination-port 63210
> -j ACCEPT
>
> iptables -A FORWARD -p udp --destination-port 63210 -j DROP

This will accept the packets for your lan, and drop everything else (for this port) which are being forwarded through the router - even if NAT is involved.   Note that it won't catch requests originating or terminating ON the router itself, for that you would use the INPUT and/or OUTPUT rather then forward chain.

The forward chain is parsed before the NAT chain so you can match source and destination IP addresses in it.

Comment: well.. i have 10.8.0.0/24 ips only on tun0... ill try

Comment: The rules I provided don't care what interface the traffic is coming in or leaving and will act on all Interfaces.